# Observing changes to database value via KVO

Tags: ios, sqlite, key-value-observing

I'm building a messaging application. I update the badge count in the database via a sqlite trigger whenever any operation like insert/delete/read message happens.

Currently, though the value update in the DB happens asynchronously, I have no way to get notified about when the value changes in my application and hence am polling periodically.

Is there some way to setup an observer on a database value/publish some notification when a given value changes?

I know that I can do this easily by first updating the badge count in an in-memory property and then persisting the changes to the DB; but I am not very inclined to do this, since there are too many entry points for this value to change, and I don't want to add a SET property everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

One possible option would be to define a trigger that is only called when this specific value in the database is updated. The trigger should then make a call to a user defined function you create in your app. You use the `sqlite3_create_function` function to add your own function to SQLite. Your trigger would like something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER some_trigger_name
AFTER UPDATE OF some_column ON some_table
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SELECT my_custom_fuction();
END;
```

If needed, you can pass 1 or more arguments to your function.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I notify my app about this change? sqlite3_create_function creates a sql function right? I want something which calls out to my objective-C code.

Comment: Using `sqlite3_create_function` you bind a SQL function to a C function in your own code. In my answer, when the `my_custom_function` SQL function is called, this will result in your own C function being called. From there you can do whatever you need.

Comment: @rmaddy, I try to use triggers but I can't create a sqlite function. Could you paste a sample code? Here's mine: sqlite3_create_function(database, "method_name", 1, SQLITE_UTF8, nil, { _, _, _ in print("changed!") }, nil, nil) The app returns: no such function: method_name in..

Answer (score 1):

Though that this might not be an option for you, Core Data does this well.